# Scaling instances with a float curve

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes, instances

[image]Hi
I have instanced an object (CYLINDER) on a BEZIER CURVE after generating points on it using geometry nodes.

I have tried to scale the instances on the z axis using as scale fator the output of a float curve, but it seems like the output is zero.

How can I sort it out?
[image]
THANKS

Answer (score 4):

Geometry primitive Points don't have a *Curve Parameter*.

Unless the attribute is captured while the geometry is still a curve, it will evaluate to 0.

Here, the *Curve Parameter* is manipulated before capture.. you could do it afterwards.

[image]

As requested, the attribute is captured on the (implicitly) evaluated *sample points* of the curve, at capture-time. Thereafter, it is linearly interpolated for other entities occupying that field, that are on the same (green) Geometry branch of the tree.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks - is there a way to scale the instances as above using a bezier curve instead of float curve?